# Installer shortcut into chm help file

Tags: installation, chm

Is it possible to provide a start menu shortcut to a specific help topic inside of a chm file?  I have not found anything that would indicate that this is possible. And I do not think it is possible since the chm is a binary file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can install a shortcut to run a command line like this:

```
hh.exe C:\path\to\my.chm::topic.html
```

where `topic.html` is the topic you want to display.